# Can't sort menu items in hexo/ejs

Tags: ejs, hexo

My site is based on a number of pages. Each one has front matter like

```
---
menutitle: "Mediator"
menuorder: 2
lang: "en"
---
```

I want to build a navbar from the pages and have

```
<% site.pages
    .filter(p => p.lang == "en")
    .sort( (i1, i2) => i1.menuorder - i2.menuorder )
    .forEach( function(item, idx) { %>
        <%- partial( 'menu_item', {data: {class: 'colour' + idx, title: item.menutitle, link: item.path}} ) %>
<% }) %>
```

my problem is that the menu order sorting never takes place and the menu items end up in what appears to be the order they were last saved! **How can I get the sorted by menuorder**

Answer (score 0):

I think site.pages is not an array but an Object. So either form an array of the pages content you want to sort and loop over, or just use `site.pages.data` instead of `site.pages` in your template above:

```
<% site.pages.data
.filter(p => p.lang == "en")
.sort( (i1, i2) => i1.menuorder - i2.menuorder )
.forEach( function(item, idx) { %>
    <%- partial( 'menu_item', {data: {class: 'colour' + idx, title: item.menutitle, link: item.path}} ) %>
<% }) %>
```